# SWT Threading: GUI not responding even after calling thread.stop()

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, thread-safety, swt

say i have this code inside a SWT button :

```
Button btn = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
btn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
//... some code...
                Thread t = new Thread(){
                    public void run()
                    {
                        //some function that includes **INFINITE LOOP** in that 
                       //sends a lot of UDP packets.
                    }
                };
                Display.getDefault().asyncExec(t); 
                try{
                Thread.sleep(5*1000);}
                catch(Exception e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                t.stop();
                System.out.println("message");
//and some more code...
```

when i run this program , approximately after 5 sec it does display in the console `message`
but then the GUI stops responding, and when i look in the task manager, i see that my cpu (i7-4700mq) isn't fully loaded - all other apps are running just fine. Not only that, i can see that the thread is still running - via Wireshark (or task manager) i can see that the udp packets are still being sent.

i need to use t.stop() because i don't have any other threads in my program, and i dont what to make the thread itself to know when to stop (by changing some parameter value) because that will reduce performance, which is extremely important in this case. 
so here are my questions:
**1.** why isn't my GUI responding like all other apps? isn't `Display.getDefault().asyncExec(t);` make the t thread run in parallel to the main(GUI) thread?

**2.** If i shouldn't use t.stop(), but can't stop the thread internally, because of performance, how should i stop it?

Answer (score 3):

asyncExec runs it in a GUI thread. Moreover, it executes Runnable. So it just calls run method of your Thread t. t is not even started, so calling stop on it does not change anything. So what actually happens is that you run an infinite loop in a GUI thread. Of course it stops responding.

Comment: but if that was true, how is it possible that the program ever reached the `System.out.println("message");` commnad?

Comment: @789 `asyncExec` schedules its argument to run later, when the GUI thread can. But it is already running your code in the selection listener, which includes this print and has to finish first before the infinite loop can start.

Comment: but if i saw that the program has sent the UDP packages even before the GUI selection listener ends.  <br> Any way, how am i spouse to tun a thread in complete concurrency in SWT? is that even possible?

Comment: @789 I don't actaully know SWT well, but standard java conurrency classes like ExecutorService and Future should work anyway.

Comment: Not true. see: [this article about SWT threading](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fswt_threading.htm). But though using ExecutorService gave me SWTException, using Future didn't, but it looks like it didn't really work at all.

Comment: @789 You can still use ExecutorService to send UDP packages. Just do not call GUI code directly from it. When you want to update GUI elements from another thread, you can use asyncExec(or syncExec).

Comment: well, i tried to make a thread that it self will contain the sending, but again it just gave SWTEXception.